# How to properly reference a thesis?

Tags: citing, thesis, ieee-style

I am using the following:

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

And I have a PhD Thesis in my references directory as show below:

```
@phdthesis{SomePerson,
author = {Some, Person},
school = {Some University},
title = {{Some very very very very very very very very very loooooooooooooooooooooooooong title}},
year = {2020}
}
```

This generates an output like this:
[image: It looks like this]

I don't understand where I am making mistake. For other 35 references everything is fine. Thank you for your contribution, in advance.

Comment: The double curly brackets may be the problem (`title = {{Some very very etc}}` instead of `title = {Some very very etc}`), do you have a particular reason for using double brackets there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have `\usepackage{ulem}` somewhere in your preamble (i.e., at the start of your document). This redefines the `\emph` command (for emphasis, by default this is printed in italics) to underline. The bibliography uses emphasis, therefore the title becomes underlined. Underlines do not always correctly handle line breaks, in this case the line in the bibliography does not get the intended line break (while in the main document underlines with `ulem` do get correct line breaks).

As a solution, the `ulem` package provides the package option `normalem` (i.e., normal emphasis) that restores emphasis to italics, which solves the problem.

To reproduce the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
\cite{SomePerson}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{ieeethesis}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}
\cite{SomePerson}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{ieeethesis}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked like a charm, and saved me from a lot of trouble.